# Best approach for unit testing with data

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

I have a lot of DAO classes I need to test on a Spring project.

I am already using *DBUnit* to mock my database, however I use the @Before annotation to create objects and compare them after tests on create/update/delete operations.

```
@DatabaseSetup(value = { "/db_data/dao/common.xml", "/db_data/dao/myDAOCommonTest.xml" })
@DbUnitConfiguration(dataSetLoader = ReplacementDataSetLoader.class)
public class MyDAOImplTest extends AbstractDaoTU {

  @Autowired
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    private Set<ClassNeeded> objectsNeeded = new HashSet<>();
    private ClassOne classOne;
    private ClassTwo classTwo;

    private ClassThree classThree;

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        this.objectsNeeded.add(somethingComingFromTheMotherClass);

        this.classOne = new ClassOne();
        this.classOne.setIdClassOne(1L)
    this.classOne.setObjectsNeeded(this.objectsNeeded);
        // ... Many other sets

        this.classTwo = new ClassTwo();
        this.classTwo.setIdClassTwo(1L);
    this.classTwo.setClassOne(this.classOne);
    // ... Many other sets

    // ... Other sets follow for a lot of other objects
    }

  @Test
  public void testOne {
    // ...
  }

  // ... Other tests follow
}
```

I am using an ORM (Hibernate in this case), and most objects are inter-dependent. My dao functions mostly need complete objects to be called, so I must create the objects before testing.

My questions are the following :

- Is there a better approach to unit test DAOs ?
- What tools do you know to make this easier/faster to write ? (I am using maven for packaging)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: That's not exactly the question but it is a good point indeed. I sometimes change some of the objects attribute values inside the tests for very specific needs, so I don't use the @BeforeClass. Is that a bad practise ? I think I'll look into it anyway, and move the objects who would be better in a BeforeClass method. Thanks for the piece of advice.

Comment: Oh ok I think we misunderstood each other. I meant writing faster. I knew about BeforeClass. As this is a big project I joined I try to follow the practises used before me. Still, I am reassured that this is not a bad practise, but I'll try to use it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. DB Unit complicates the maintenance of the tests as it increases the number of places that need updates when something changes. Additionally it separates the data preparation from the tests too much so it's hard to find which of the data relates to which tests.
2. Ideally each test prepares data for itself. This removes global state and keeps related things together.

To prepare the data just create entities and save them in the very same test. You can use randomization and transaction rollbacks to isolate the tests. Here is an example from one of my projects:

```
@Test public void returnsExperimentAsItWasSaved() {
    Experiment original = Experiment.random();
    experimentRepository.save(original);
    flushToDbAndClearCache();

    Experiment fromDb = experimentRepository.findOne(original.getExperimentId());
    assertReflectionEquals(original, fromDb);
}
```

Note, that the very same DAO class is used to prepare the data.

Comment: Do you mean using an Entity Manager (I know the Jhipster framework uses that kind of thing in its tests) ? Data that is common to each test should still be initialized in @before ? Or is it not readable enough ?

Comment: It's very unreadable in @Before when you get to 10-20 tests because you'd have to prepare completely unrelated objects there. You can use the very same DAO class to prepare data (updated my answer).

Comment: Ok then, I'll try to do that. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to develop your tests as you would develop your code: refactor to minimize duplication, extract reusable services, etc.

So, you'll probably create some TestCaseFactory that chains up a whole set of objects and saves them using your actual DAO's. Then, you can call them from an @Before as you did. If you need a lot of different sets of objects, you can create different methods or a parameter object etc.

And do a cleanup of all test data in an @After.